# Rotate left & right box sides and not content

Tags: html, css

I want to accomplish the image below:

[image]

Without rotating the box itself, only the borders of left & right. The image shows only left & right border angled a few %.

I've tried `border-bottom-right-radius` & `transform: rotate()`.

Comment: You can use `transform:rotate()`, just only apply it to a child element that renders the background

Comment: The background is parent of the content. Rotating this will rotate all box. 
If you look at the image the top & bottom of the card isnt rotated, only the sides. @KevinJantzer

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use a pseudo-element stacked behind the container, and skew that instead of the container element

```css
.pricing{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.number{font-size:4rem;}

.pricing:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  background:SlateBlue;
  transform: skewX(-5deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing">
  <p>Student</p>
  <p class="number">1234</p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas voluptate explicabo vero cumque vitae odit laudantium sapiente unde mollitia deleniti ullam, cum laborum deserunt dolorum soluta nulla dolor accusamus dignissimos!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set a before on the container and set that to be the blue background you can simply use skewX or skewY to get the effect you want.

```
.block:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:blue;
    transform: skewX(10deg);
}
```

https://codepen.io/dangvanthanh/pen/EbKlw Will let you see how it works

You can get more info in the more info in the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew

Comment: This skews all container box. I just want the left & right to be skewed

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is apply the transform to the parent element, and *inverse* the transform on it's children elements

```
div {
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

div .child {
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

Comment: This skews all container box. I just want the left & right to be skewed

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: the top & bottom width of the box should not be skewed. Only the height of left & right borders. 

So top & bottom should still be at 0deg skew & left & right should be slightly rotated.